# Command failed: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object X, database Y, schema 'dbo'

Tags: sql-server, azure, job-scheduling

I created new database-scoped credentials as well as a new target group to run my jobs on an Azure SQL Database and with the help of an **Elastic Job Agent**. The Elastic Job Agent is merely there and tied to the database on which I am running the job. Other than that, it does not play any part in running the following commands.

The job is only one step and in that step, I assign `@credential_name` to the credential that I created and `@target_group_name` to the newly created target group.

```
EXEC jobs.sp_add_job @job_name='UpdatePowerBIReport'
    , @description='Update the Power BI Report by calling the stored procedure';
 
-- And add the job step 
EXEC jobs.sp_add_jobstep 
      @job_name='UpdatePowerBIReport'
    , @command = N'EXEC dbo.UpdatePowerBI;'
    , @credential_name= 'ElasticJobUserCredential'
    , @target_group_name='MyTargetGroup'
```

As you see in the command, the job only runs a stored procedure called under the `dbo` schema called `UpdatePowerBI`.

When I run the job and monitor its execution it fails with the following message:

> Command failed: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
> 'UpdatePowerBI', database 'MYDBNAME', schema 'dbo'. (Msg 229, Level
> 14, State 5, Line 1)

I am running this command in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

On the target database, have you completed the following:

1 Created a USER with the same name and password as the Credential in the Job Database
2 GRANTED the EXECUTE permission to that USER on the Stored Procedure?

The error message is clear that the user context that is calling the procedure has not been granted the permissions to do so.

Comment: Hi Martin! (1) I actually haven't created a separate db for jobs. I know that the docs says so, but in another question they told me it is possible for the job and target database to be the same. We have currently one database only. We should maybe change the solution when more come in play. (2) No. I did not know that it was needed. I will look to find the statement for that, but feel free to enlighten me as I do.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I added the newly created user as a member of the role `db_owner`. Feel free to update your answer so I accept it. Big thanks!